# Why AdMob interstitial lock UI thread?

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

While using Method Tracing util, I encountered a problem with Android AdMob interstitial ads.

Now I use the latest version of AdMob:

> ```
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
> ```

And this code:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
Log.d(TAG, "load: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
```

prints:

> ```
> load: 1250 ms
> ```

and locks UI thread.

Example device: LG G3 Android 5.0.

I don't understand why it locks.

P.S. logs

```
09-08 11:35:52.294 I/Ads: Starting ad request.
09-08 11:35:52.297 I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("C847646CE34895E5C61DEA64E092F1A5") to get test ads on this device.
09-08 11:35:53.157 W/Ads: The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
09-08 11:35:53.224 E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)
09-08 11:35:53.546 I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 30000 milliseconds from now.
09-08 11:35:53.553 I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

**P.S.2**

I look up answer for my question in official AdMob Googe Group
[Answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/loadAds%7Csort:relevance/google-admob-ads-sdk/k4IFZA_QGT4/3gMHaCPPBQAJ)

Comment: can you please write in detail, locks UI thread means? Is it stopping your app from running? Interstitial ads are full-screen ads that cover the interface of their host app. They should run on top of your activity. If you don't want this to happen you can always opt for banner ads

Comment: Lock UI means: freeze UI animation. And my problem with loadAds(), not with show(). I use AdMob more 4 years and no had this problem early.

Comment: are there any exceptions in logs?

Comment: No, any bugs in the log. Interstitial loaded and then I invoke show it showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a bug and should be reported to the Firebase team. I'm looking at the [InterstitialAd documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd#loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)), and it clearly says for `loadAd`:

> Start loading the ad on a background thread.

If it takes such a long time to complete this method, I'm pretty sure that it actually didn't use the background thread or at least didn't do it properly. You can try making this call on a slow network, in which case I think you will get an ANR. That should confirm that this is a blocking call.

Comment: Good idea)  I look up answer in AdMob Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-admob-ads-sdk/loadAds|sort:relevance/google-admob-ads-sdk/k4IFZA_QGT4/3gMHaCPPBQAJ